# Matplotlib plotsize- Size not changing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-matrix, figsize

The size of the of this plot is coming out to be <Figure size 864x432 with 0 Axes>

```
plt.figure(figsize =(12,6))
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(Effect_Wf_f)
plt.show()
```

1. Why is it not changing? -- despite writing before the plotting code.
2. Is `` sns.set_style('whitegrid`) `` could be problem?

Comment: That figures size in in pixels, whereas the figsize parameter is in inches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that the plot size is changed by the plotting function. Add at the end:

```
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(12,6)
```

There is also a `figsize` parameter in [`pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix.html)

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I end up using this. ```pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(Effect_Wf_f)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(12,6)
plt.show()```